# Remove Whitespace After a Macro

Tags: macros, white-space

I am trying to remove the white spaces following a custom macro. I am having the worst time understanding what is happening. I have looked through most of the answers here for how to remove white spaces but I cannot get it to work correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\programName}{m}{%
  \textbf{#1} program
} 

\begin{document}
I want to use the \programName{ProperItem}.
I want to use the \textbf{ProperItem} program.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put another % right after programm ... i.e. at the end of each line inside a macro definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\programName}{m}{%
  \textbf{#1} program
}
```

with

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\programName}{m}{%
  \textbf{#1} program}
```

If you don't want to move the closing curly brace up one line as suggested above, do place a `%` (comment symbol) immediately after `program`.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand{\programName}{m}{%
  \textbf{#1} program} 

\begin{document}
I want to use the \programName{ProperItem}.

I want to use the \textbf{ProperItem} program.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had a brain fart and thought I had already added the "%" to it. I have the "}" on the next line because the stupid opinionated code formatter keeps messing indenting the rest of the lines.